# Rails custom route not found when testing, but works for curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rails-routing, testunit

In config/routes.rb:

```
match 'app_config/:version' => "application#appconfig"
```

test/functional/application_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'
class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "app config" do
    get "/app_config/v2"
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

`rake test`:

```
  1) Error:
test_app_config(ApplicationControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"application", :action=>"/app_config/v2"}
```

but `$ curl localhost:3000/app_config/v2` works, and returns the response I expect, and `rake routes` shows the route as expected. Any idea what's going on, or how to investigate further? This is basically the only code in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` method does not take a route. It takes an action name and a parameter's hash.

If you want to test the action, your tests should look like this:

```
test "for success" do
  get :appconfig, :version => "v2"
  assert_response :success
end
```

If you want to test routing there is a [tutorial here in the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-routes).

```
test "should route to appconfig" do
  assert_routing '/app_config/v2', { :controller => "application", :action => "appconfig", :version => "v2" }
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I presumed that `get` could take a route, because of `get '/'` in the generated performance tests.